# Magento_beforeSave for customer entity

Tags: php, magento

Magento calls _beforeSave function to process the object before saving the data. the access of the function is protected. (as per the magento documentation)

Was debugging how magento saves customer entity. _beforeSave data is getting called from Customer/Model/Customer.php which in turn calls parent::_beforeSave (Mage_Core_Model_Abstract).

But still unable to find from where the function is getting called. There must be some call to be made to run this function and where is it written??

The function always runs but can not find from where and how it is called??

Answer (score 1):

This method is called in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()` method on line 316 just before calling the `save()` method in resource object.

So, when Magento call this method, it runs the overrided `_beforeSave()` method present in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` that calls `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()` (initialize object as new if not has an id and dispatch events) and execute the remaining code present in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_beforeSave()`

Comment: It is calling method _beforeSave of  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract class. but _beforeSave is also defined in customer model class. how it is called??

Comment: Magento calls _beforeSave like $this->_beforeSave(). then call goes to the function of same class...  then how Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_beforeSave() is executed??? Is DispatchEvent written in _beforeSave calls the customer class???

Comment: No, magento calls the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_beforeSave() because this model override _beforeSave method of Mage_Core_Model_Abstract. In Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_beforeSave() it's called parent::_beforeSave() that executes Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave() because this class is a parent of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer. Learn about class inheritance here http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php